# Duvida com random em c++14 e 17

Tags: c++, random, c++14

Eu estava pesquisando na internet como fazer números pseudo-aleatórios em c++ e todos exemplos que eu achei era com a função srand, mas em alguns lugares o pessoal falava que srand é do c, e o c++ já tem uma biblioteca melhor para criar números aleatórios, eu pesquisei na internet mas em português eu não achei nada sobre isso, então eu fui em uma documentação do c++ e achei esse trecho de código

```
int gerar_aleatorio(){
    random_device r;
    default_random_engine e1(r());
    uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(1, 100);
    return uniform_dist(e1);
}
```

ele deu certo, mas eu não entendi o que ele está fazendo em cada linha, dei uma pesquisada mas não acho nada em pt, gostaria de entender o que está sendo feito em cada linha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Desde [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), a biblioteca para geração e distribuição de números aleatórios [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) foi introduzida para resolver esse grande buraco que existia em [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) anteriormente, como você já notou. A cppreference tem uma versão traduzida (boa parte automaticamente) para Português, basta apenas colocar `pt.` no lugar de `en.` no link: [`<random>` em Português](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). Está um pouco desatualizado, mas deve ajudar. A página em Inglês é completa, entretanto.

Enfim, vamos para a dissecação do código agora:

```
std::random_device r;
std::default_random_engine e1(r());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(1, 100);
return uniform_dist(e1);
```

A primeira linha constrói um [`std::random_device`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device), um gerador de números aleatórios não-determinístico<sup>1</sup> (isto é, seria uma verdadeiro gerador de números aleatórios, e não pseudoaleatório). Esse é um dos vários geradores que existem na biblioteca padrão. O uso básico desse gerador é chamar o operador de chamada de função `operator()` para gerar o próximo número aleatório e avançar o estado do gerador:

```
std::random_device rd;
auto N = rd(); // N contém o número aleatório gerado por rd()
```

No caso do `std::random_device`, a fonte de entropia não vem de uma semente. Em algumas implementações, como a [libc++](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/661dff0e60093266e7833cbbf5d3809a4f950378/include/random#L3500) e a [libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B11/random.cc?view=markup), a fonte de entropia por padrão é a `/dev/urandom` em sistemas Unix-like, em vez de uma semente. Outros geradores (de números pseudoaleatórios) na biblioteca padrão aceitam uma semente como fonte de entropia, que pode ser o caso do `std::default_random_engine`.

`std::default_random_engine` pode não ser igual entre implementações, já que seu motor é deixado como *implementation-defined* (ou seja, a critério da implementação). Os únicos requirimentos recomendados são que a seleção desse motor forneça, pelo menos, [um comportamento aceitável para uso relativamente casual, inexperiente e/ou leve](http://eel.is/c++draft/rand.predef#10.note-1). O motor [`std::linear_congruential_engine`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/linear_congruential_engine) é normalmente usado com alguns parâmetros específicos para definir o `std::default_random_engine`.

Voltando ao código:

```
std::default_random_engine e1(r());
```

Essa linha constrói um motor de números pseudoaleatórios (definido pela implementação), com uma semente, cujo número é gerado por `r()`, como fonte de entropia. Isto é, o motor `r` foi utilizado apenas para gerar a semente de um outro motor `e1`. Como esse código foi tirado de dentro de uma função, esse tipo de tática não é boa, uma vez que sempre ao chamar a função `gerar_aleatorio()`, dois motores serão construídos, um deles semeados e apenas a primeira geração de número é realizada. O mais correto seria utilizar um único motor construído para o programa inteiro e usar algum distribuidor (como o [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) nesse caso) pra gerar os números aleatórios. Outra solução é fazer o `e1` ser `thread_local`, pois assim sua inicialização é feita apenas uma vez para cada thread.

Indo para a próxima linha no código, temos:

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(1, 100);
```

Essa distribuição é uma de várias outras na biblioteca padrão. Distribuidores de números aleatórios pós-processam o número gerado por um motor de números aleatórios, de modo que o resultado seja distribuído de acordo com uma dada função de densidade probabilística estatística. Em outras palavras, o resultado de um distribuidor segue um padrão estatístico. Em específico, o distribuidor `std::uniform_int_distribution` produz um número que siga uma distribuição uniforme (ou seja, cada número no intervalo terá quase a mesma quantidade de vezes gerado estatisticamente). Esse intervalo é dado ao construí-lo através dos parâmetros do construtor (no caso do seu código, esse intervalo é `[1, 100]` inclusivo).

Finalmente, a última linha:

```
return uniform_dist(e1);
```

O distribuidor do `uniform_dist` tem um [`operator()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution/operator()) parecido com o de um motor: cada chamada gera o próximo número aleatório e atualiza/avança o estado do motor/distribuidor. A diferença é que, no caso do distribuidor, ele recebe como parâmetro um motor de números aleatórios. Como dito antes, isso é necessário, pois um distribuidor apenas aplica uma função de densidade no número aleatório gerado por um motor. Quem realmente gera o número aleatório é o motor, já o distribuidor apenas faz uso dessa saída. O resultado de `uniform_dist(e1)` avança o estado do motor `e1` e do distribuidor `uniform_dist` e gera um número pseudoaleatório uniformemente distribuído dentro do intervalo `[1, 100]`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Uma implementação pode definir o gerador `std::random_device` em termos de um gerador de números pseudoaleatórios caso não houver uma fonte não-determinística.

Comment: Excelente resposta. Lembrando que `<random>` foi introduzido no C++11. Para versões jurásicas do C++ uma alternativa confiável é a biblioteca `Boost.Random` (desconfio que `<random>` foi fortemente baseado no Boost).

Comment: Cara muito obrigado mesmo! deu pra entender linha por linha, só uma dúvida, tem algum motor que é mais aconselhável usar?

Comment: @zaque para uso casual, `std::default_random_engine` é suficiente. Dê uma lida nas descrições de cada motor na cppreference caso sentir que tenha um caso específico e que um motor apropriado seja necessário.